# Removing all punctuation apart from single apostrophes and hyphens within words

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I've asked a similar question before, but this one is much more specific and will require a different solution than the one provided previously, so I hope it's OK to post it. I need to keep only apostrophes and within-word dashes in my text (remove all other punctuation). For example, I want to get str2 from str1:

```
str1<-"I'm dash before word -word, dash &%$,. in-between word, two before word --word just dashes ------, between words word - word"
str2<-"I'm dash before word word dash in-between word two before word  word just dashes  between words word  word"
```

The solution I have so far, first removes dashes between words:
    `gsub(" - ", " ", str1)`

and then leaves alphabetic and numeric characters plus remaining dashes
    `gsub("[^[:alnum:]['-]", " ", str1)`

The problem is, it doesn’t remove dashes following each other, e.g. “—“ and dashes at the beginning and end of words: “-word” or “word—“

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this does it:

```
gsub('( |^)-+|-+( |$)', '\\1', gsub("[^ [:alnum:]'-]", '', str1))
#[1] "I'm dash before word word dash  in-between word two before word word just dashes  between words word  word"
```

Comment: Sweet, thank you. I understand this ' -+|-+ ' means: replace a dash if it occurs 1 or more times before a word or after, but I thought the "|" is used for alternation match (e.g. /(e|d)n/ matches "en" and "dn"). I wonder if it is used in a similar way in your solution and whether the spaces at the beginning and end have a meaning...

Comment: `' -+|-+ '` means "a space followed by 1 or more dashes OR 1 or more dashes followed by a space"

Comment: After some testing, I noticed there are still some undesirable dashes in my text, I guess my question wasn't precise enough. Can you help? The suggested line does not remove multiple dashes before words or in between like in this string:    string3<-"---before word, two or more between word--word, at the end--" I would like only single within-word dashes to be kept.

Comment: @user3722736 I modified to take care of starting/ending dashes. You can add another `gsub` to get rid of remaining multiple dashes between words: `gsub('-+', '-', above_result)`

Answer (score 4):

Here is an approach:

```
gsub("([[:alnum:]][[:punct:]][[:alnum:]])|[[:punct:]]", "\\1", str1)
# [1] "I'm dash before word word dash  in-between word two before word word just dashes  between words word  word"
```

Or, more explicitly:

```
gsub("([[:alnum:]]['-][[:alnum:]])|[[:punct:]]", "\\1", str1)
```

Same thing, slightly different / shorter:

```
gsub("(\\w['-]\\w)|[[:punct:]]", "\\1", str1, perl=TRUE)
```

Comment: The last option is brilliant, should be selected as the right answer

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

```
x <- "I'm dash before word -word, dash &%$,. in-between word, two before word --word just dashes ------, between words word - word"
gsub("\\b([-'])\\b|[[:punct:]]+", "\\1", x, perl=TRUE)
# =>  "I'm dash before word word dash  in-between word two before word word just dashes  between words word  word"
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/av1q4P).  The regex is

```
\b([-'])\b|[[:punct:]]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IOhFI0/1). Details:

- `\b([-'])\b` - `-` or `'` enclosed with word chars (letters, digits or `_`) (NOTE: if you only want to keep in between letters, use `(?<=\p{L})([-'])(?=\p{L})` instead)
- `|` - or
- `[[:punct:]]+` - 1 or more punctuation symbols.

To remove any leading/trailing, and double whitespace chars that result after this replacement, you may use

```
res <- gsub("\\b([-'])\\b|[[:punct:]]+", "\\1", x, perl=TRUE)
res <- trimws(gsub("\\s{2,}", " ", res))
```